# Converting an unusual hex long lat to a mapped destination in the IM Line

Tags: hex, latitude-longitude, computer-forensics

Help,

I have recently located a Hex long/lat value in the registry for the IM line. 
I am trying to confirm it is the users location and not the IM provider.

I have seen conversion methods suggest on previous questions but the hex value is shorter.

Does anybody know how to convert

Lat: 51 6B 9A 77 9C 32 4A 40

Long: 49 2E FF 21 FD F6 F8 BF
Thanks

Comment: What's an IM? Do you have an approximate idea where the location is? Do you know which program stored the value?

Comment: IM is instant messenger and the instant messenge rin question is 'LINE'.